# How to add a new buffer to opening nvim-qt instead of opening a new instance on Windows?

Tags: neovim, neovim-qt

I have set up nvim-qt version 0.6 on my Windows 10 to use it instead of Notepad++. And when I double-click on a file, a new nvim-qt instance will open. But now, what I want is if I double-click on a file, nvim-qt will open a new buffer in running nvim-qt instead of opening a new nvim-qt instance. It will save me a lot of time. Do you know any way to do that? please help.

Thanks,

Comment: There's https://github.com/mhinz/neovim-remote but I believe it doesn't work on Windows...

Comment: @filbranden, anyway, thank you for your answer